# MysQL - Aggregate Datetime Row splitting

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions

Can some help me with the below MySQL challenge please  ?

The reported data is broken down by hour within the selected date. If a device_table indicates that the device is unavailable across several hours it will be reported within each of those hours, e.g. if device held records for a device as follows,

```
select * from device_table

+----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| id |   Start_timestamp   |    End_timestamp    | STATUS |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | 28/11/2014 13:26:25 | 28/11/2014 13:36:22 | UP     |
|  2 | 28/11/2014 13:36:23 | 28/11/2014 14:06:27 | DN     |
|  3 | 28/11/2014 14:06:28 | 28/11/2014 14:06:28 | UP     |
|  4 | 28/11/2014 14:06:29 | 28/11/2014 14:11:26 | DN     |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

Then the device would be reported as unavailable both in hours 13:00 & 14:00 as the second record falls in both these hours and the last record also falls in hour 14:00.

how to split the records and form a query to achieve the above  and count the up and down device based on their hours?

**I want some thing like this if a device is down from 28/11/2014 13:36:23 to 28/11/2014 14:06:27 then my query should count the device was down at 2 hours  i.e 13:36:23 & 14:06:27 and also if my device is down at 28/11/2014 13:36:23 t0 28/11/2014 13:46:27 then my device should be reported as down for one hour only i.e 13.00 hours**

The output of the query should be like below

```
+-------+----+-------+-----------------+
| Hours | up | down  |  total(UP+DOWN) |
+-------+----+-------+-----------------+
| 00.00 |  1 |     0 |               1 |
| 01.00 |  1 |     1 |               2 |
| 02.00 |  0 |     0 |               0 |
|  : :  |    |       |                 |
|  : :  |    |       |                 |
| 23:00 |  0 |     1 |               1 |
+-------+----+-------+-----------------+
```

Comment: what about using a concat ??

Comment: concat on which Avinash  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the following query a try.

```
SELECT `tab_a`.`ID`, `tab_a`.`start-date-time`, `tab_a`.`end-date-time`,
  `tab_a`.`timediff`, `tab_a`.`status`
FROM `tab_a`
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT `tens`.`count` * 10 + `ones`.`count` AS `num-hours`
  FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS `count` UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION
    SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
  ) `ones`
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS `count` UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION
    SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
  ) `tens`
) `increment`
  ON (
    `tab_a`.`start-date-time` + INTERVAL `increment`.`num-hours` HOUR
    < `tab_a`.`end-date-time`
  )
```

**Added solution to modified question**

The following query should do what you're wanting for the preceding seven-day period.

```
SELECT `dates`.`date`, `times`.`hour`,
  CASE WHEN (COALESCE(COUNT(`device_up`.`ID`), 0) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `up`,
  CASE WHEN (COALESCE(COUNT(`device_dn`.`ID`), 0) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `down`,
  CASE WHEN (COALESCE(COUNT(`device_up`.`ID`), 0) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN (COALESCE(COUNT(`device_dn`.`ID`), 0) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `up-down`
FROM (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL `count` DAY, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `date`
  FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS `count` UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
  ) `ones`
) `dates`
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT `sixes`.`count` * 4 + `fours`.`count` AS `hour`
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 AS `count` UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION
    SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
  ) `sixes`
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS `count` UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
  ) `fours`
) `times`
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT `ID`, `Start_timestamp`, `End_timestamp`
  FROM `device_table`
  WHERE (`status` = 'UP')
) `device_up`
  ON (
    (`device_up`.`Start_timestamp` < `dates`.`date` + INTERVAL `times`.`hour` + 1 HOUR)
    AND (`device_up`.`End_timestamp` > `dates`.`date` + INTERVAL `times`.`hour` HOUR)
  )
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT `ID`, `Start_timestamp`, `End_timestamp`
  FROM `device_table`
  WHERE (`status` = 'DN')
) `device_dn`
  ON (
    (`device_dn`.`Start_timestamp` < `dates`.`date` + INTERVAL `times`.`hour` + 1 HOUR)
    AND (`device_dn`.`End_timestamp` > `dates`.`date` + INTERVAL `times`.`hour` HOUR)
  )
GROUP BY `dates`.`date`, `times`.`hour`
ORDER BY `dates`.`date`, `times`.`hour`
```

Comment: Thanks for the Quick reply paul rowe . but if the time diff is 2 hours it has to split 2 rows if the time diff is 12 hours for the start n end time it has to split into 12 records  like wise .. the above query splits only 2 records for every hour time stamp is down

Comment: @TobyWintio I see. I misunderstood the requirements. Let me think about this a bit more.

Comment: Thank you very much Much appreciated for your support .

Comment: @TobyWintio I've edited the answer so that it will generate a record for each hour up to 100 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the Efforts Paul Rowse .. it was good but dint go well with my requirement unfortunately .. but from ur ideas i think i should start trying this out .. thanks so much for helping me up to here . much appreciated paul

Comment: i have just updated the whole requirement please kindly let me know if that's possible to achieve it

Comment: @TobyWintio Let me make sure I understand the new requirement. You want to get a report for each one-hour block of time for each date in the specified range with a flag for up and a flag for down. If, at any point in time during that one-hour block the server was up, the flag for up will be true. A similar condition would apply to the flag for down. Let me know if that's correct.

Comment: @TobyWintio I think I can come up with a solution for this. Should this be a new question?

Comment: Yes Paul we can have them as a new Question  too if you would like

Comment: @TobyWintio I modified the answer to address the modified requirement.

Comment: Thank yu so much paul .it works like a charm  .. Just it would be nice if yu cud tell me how to change this code just for one day  alone ..  7 days is too much to be shown .. just one day will be fine  Also please tell me where i can change the HOUR display as 00.00 , 01.00 , 02:00 .... 23.00

Comment: @TobyWintio You can modify the `dates` subquery so it only gets one record and that will get you only one day. You can perform a `CAST` on `hour` to turn it into a `VARCHAR` and do some string manipulation to get the desired format.

Comment: Thank u paul its great u helped me so much with loads of gratitude

Answer (score 1):

What's your upper bound on timediff?

```
select *
from tab_a as t,
    (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2...) as duplicator
where t.timediff < duplicator.n
```